# Making a div/span display its content on top of the right side of a larger div/span?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So basically I have

```
<div>Option 1</div>
<span>Here is some text that would naturally require options</span>
```

So i want the Option 1 text to be on top of the right side of the span.

Is this possible? (This is for a fluid layout so I'd rather not use px... or % for that matter. If it's possible to do it somehow with text-align:right or float:right or some weird display: configuration, that would be ideal.)

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnl3y.jpg to clarify my horrible explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***HTML :***

```
<div id="container">
    <div>Option 1</div>
    <div>Here is some text that would naturally require options</div>
</div>
```

***CSS :***

```css
#container { display:table; margin: 0 auto; }
#container > div { text-align: right; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KpL2/3/)

Comment: Thanks but one question- what if I wanted the all the text to be situated in the center of the screen. Like the top text would be on the right side of the bottom text, like your jsfiddle has now, but everything together would be in the center. Also, what html structure would you reccomend?

Comment: Thanks! For general knowledge's sake, what's the > css thing

Comment: Does it only select the first child?

Comment: @Kpower : all children, to select the first you can use `first-child`.